# How to allow access to the Python Socket.py file when using buildozer to create a mobile app?

Tags: python, linux, kivy, buildozer, python-sockets

I am having trouble using the Python Socket module while building a mobile app using Buildozer. The program seems to not have the permissions to access the socket.py file, but I don't know how to fix it. The code that has what I believe to be the error message from the debug logs is displayed below.

```
2021-08-01 20:05:53.572 12099-12117/org.test.myapp6 I/python:  Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-08-01 20:05:53.572 12099-12117/org.test.myapp6 I/python:    File "/home/ubuntu/mobile_app/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 47, in <module>
2021-08-01 20:05:53.573 12099-12117/org.test.myapp6 I/python:    File "/home/ubuntu/mobile_app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp6/kivy/app.py", line 855, in run
2021-08-01 20:05:53.574 12099-12117/org.test.myapp6 I/python:    File "/home/ubuntu/mobile_app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp6/kivy/base.py", line 504, in runTouchApp
2021-08-01 20:05:53.575 12099-12117/org.test.myapp6 I/python:    File "/home/ubuntu/mobile_app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp6/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 747, in mainloop
2021-08-01 20:05:53.575 12099-12117/org.test.myapp6 I/python:    File "/home/ubuntu/mobile_app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp6/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 479, in _mainloop
2021-08-01 20:05:53.576 12099-12117/org.test.myapp6 I/python:    File "/home/ubuntu/mobile_app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp6/kivy/base.py", line 342, in idle
2021-08-01 20:05:53.577 12099-12117/org.test.myapp6 I/python:    File "/home/ubuntu/mobile_app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp6/kivy/base.py", line 327, in dispatch_input
2021-08-01 20:05:53.577 12099-12117/org.test.myapp6 I/python:    File "/home/ubuntu/mobile_app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp6/kivy/base.py", line 233, in post_dispatch_input
2021-08-01 20:05:53.578 12099-12117/org.test.myapp6 I/python:    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
2021-08-01 20:05:53.579 12099-12117/org.test.myapp6 I/python:    File "/home/ubuntu/mobile_app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp6/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 1402, in on_motion
2021-08-01 20:05:53.579 12099-12117/org.test.myapp6 I/python:    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
2021-08-01 20:05:53.580 12099-12117/org.test.myapp6 I/python:    File "/home/ubuntu/mobile_app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp6/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 1418, in on_touch_down
2021-08-01 20:05:53.581 12099-12117/org.test.myapp6 I/python:    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
2021-08-01 20:05:53.581 12099-12117/org.test.myapp6 I/python:    File "/home/ubuntu/mobile_app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp6/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 549, in on_touch_down
2021-08-01 20:05:53.582 12099-12117/org.test.myapp6 I/python:    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
2021-08-01 20:05:53.582 12099-12117/org.test.myapp6 I/python:    File "/home/ubuntu/mobile_app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp6/kivy/uix/behaviors/button.py", line 151, in on_touch_down
2021-08-01 20:05:53.583 12099-12117/org.test.myapp6 I/python:    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 703, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
2021-08-01 20:05:53.584 12099-12117/org.test.myapp6 I/python:    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1214, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
2021-08-01 20:05:53.585 12099-12117/org.test.myapp6 I/python:    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1138, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
2021-08-01 20:05:53.585 12099-12117/org.test.myapp6 I/python:    File "/home/ubuntu/mobile_app/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 38, in send_alert
2021-08-01 20:05:53.586 12099-12117/org.test.myapp6 I/python:    File "/home/ubuntu/mobile_app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/socket.py", line 231, in __init__
2021-08-01 20:05:53.587 12099-12117/org.test.myapp6 I/python:  PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
2021-08-01 20:05:53.587 12099-12117/org.test.myapp6 I/python: Python for android ended.``'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Socket.py is python prebuild library and you dont need to import it in the buildozer.spec be sure to uncomment the android.permission line with INTERNET acess so the socket can function properly.

**for python3 and kivy 2.0.0 (even with socket)**

```
requirements = python3,kivy=2.0.0
```

**permissions line**

```
android.permissions = INTERNET
```

Comment: Thank you, the permissions line edit about enabling internet permissions fixed the issue.